# What is the proper REST call to get m:properties --> d:Id, d:ID but not the GUID ID XML elements?

Tags: list, rest

Please see attached JPEG to demonstrate what I'm asking.  Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

Try using $expand OData to query as the Author field itself is a separate object.

> Example :
>   http://server/site/_api/web/lists('guid')/items?$select=Title,Author/Id&$expand=Author/Id

Answer (score 0):

Modify your rest api call to include

```
&$expand=Author&$select=Author/Id
```

Then retrieve value using

```
console.log(items[0].Author.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like metadata -- it includes the etag and other rest endpoint to update the item. Those are very useful pieces of information and I'm not sure you can eliminate them entirely. Not sure why you would want to supress that.

This post talks about [JSON light support](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/) which can flatten and somewhat reduce the size of the data coming back.

In a normal request you included an `accept` header with the value `application\json;odata=verbose`.

That page says change the value to `application/json;odata=minimaldata`.